# Merging data with a dates table gives strange behaviour when some recordfield is added

Tags: grouping, crystal-reports-xi

I'm using Crystel Reports again after not touching it for about 8 years.

I'm having this situation...

I have 1 data table, and 1 table with just day numbers from 1 to 31.
Nothing is really linked between each other.

In my report I let the user select a reference date.

From that date I grab the maximum days of the month.

The report lists a row per day of that month but there are no actual database fields inthere. Just the first 2 letters of the dayname, the day number and another formula based field showing 'yes/no' or '' depending on a main record value.

So far so good.

In the group header I was adding the fields from the main datatable which went all fine until I added fields that in the query on the sql server rely on some cases but CR just read it out as 1 singe record row with everything in it.

For some reason the report generation goes from 1-2 seconds to 30-40 once I add that field that just outputs 'X' or ''. (it represents things assigned to that user)

Other reports where I'm using the same data still generate in 2 seconds.

To get this working right and to eleminate double date records I'm stuck with 3 groups.

I think this ain't optimal and the reason for the slow down although it wasn't there at the start.

So I was wondering:

Should I go for a sub report for the day listing?
Can I feed the subreport with my date parameter?

or is there some kind of scripted way to list a row x-times without all the grouping requirements?

Comment: It sounds like it's the queries that are problematic rather than crystal reports, so profile them by themselves, and if you still have trouble, post them here.

Comment: a small side note, it appears that the culprit is the sort in the report > record sort expert. When I remove it it takes again 2 seconds. No idea why it would cause such a slowdown on 176 records tho.

Comment: from where are you getting `day listing` and what data you get from `datatable` and how data from both linked together and if there is no linking between tables then why are you using those in reports?

Comment: can show how your report looks like?

Comment: I just use the day table to list all the days of the month, it's some kind of sheet that display what a specific user has of "features". I'll upload a screenshot.

Comment: I changed it to a subreport which does everything right without all the grouping but still slow as hell when applying the sort on that specific klas (class) field. It also happends when I do that in the view on the sql server so it's indeed a query issue somewhere. > https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgyvw0hg6cx1v6r/img1.png

Comment: Alright, I seem to have solved it. One of the joined views had a where someid between 211 and 265 or id=67 that caused some serious slow down when the result that came out of there was sorted. I move that check to the top level and now it takes 2 second with sort to class and user added. Case closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchro was right, the problem was in the actual query/view.

For some reason the view takes half a minute longer if you just added an order by to a specific field.

The "where id between 211 and 265 or id=67" has been moved from a joined view to the actual query.

Thanks for the hint, Synchro.